# Prove: If $f, g$ real, bounded on $[a,b]$ than for any partition $\pi,$ $U(f+g, \pi) \leq U(f\pi) + U(g, \pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I think I've proved the statement above, but would like some thoughts if at all possible. I've restated the problem below.

> Suppose $f, g$ real and bounded on $[a,b]$. Then show for any partition $\pi$: $U(f+g, \pi) \leq U(f,\pi) + U(g, \pi)$. Where $U$ is the upper sum.

First, I will show for $a \leq  x_1 < x_2 \leq b$ that:

$\sup_{x\in(x_1, x_2)} f + g \leq \sup_{x\in(x_1, x_2)}f + \sup_{x\in(x_1, x_2)}g$

Note that since $f, g$ are real and bounded then they have least upper bounds so:

for $x \in (x_1, x_2) \subset [a,b], \ f \leq \sup_{x \in(x_1,x_2)}f$ and $g \leq \sup_{x \in(x_1,x_2)}g$.

Adding these inequalities we have:

$f + g \leq \sup_{x \in(x_1,x_2)}f + \sup_{x \in(x_1,x_2)}g.$

Clearly, $f+g$ is bounded and real and so it has a least upper bound, and by definition we have:

$\sup_{x\in(x_1, x_2)}f + g \leq \sup_{x \in(x_1,x_2)}f + \sup_{x \in(x_1,x_2)}g$.

Now, multiplying by $(x_2 - x_1) > 0$ we get:

$(x_2 - x_1)\sup_{x\in(x_1, x_2)}f + g \leq (x_2 -x_1)\sup_{x \in(x_1,x_2)}f + (x_2 - x_1)\sup_{x \in(x_1,x_2)}g$.

Now summing from $0$ to $n-1$,

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1} - x_i)\sup_{x\in(x_i, x_{i+1}\ )}f + g \leq \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1} -x_i)\sup_{x \in(x_i,x_{i+1} \ )}f + \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1} - x_i)\sup_{x \in(x_i,x_{i+1} \ )}g$.

And so, by definition we have:

$U(f+g, \pi) \leq U(f,\pi) + U(g, \pi)$

Comment: Looks fine to me.